# Selecting data of a 'person'' using LIMIT from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-limit

I was wondering how to fetch data of a person from a table. I found the query to `LIMIT` data fetch from table. Here is what I got so far:

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username[$x] . "' LIMIT " . $last_limt . " , " . $nxt_limt . "");
```

It returns data when `LIMIT` is available but if the `LIMIT` exceed the entire data returns null. So how can I know if ROW is available or not in table?

Comment: When you reached to the  limit and you still trying to fetch rows from table it not return any records as the limit of records you are fetching are not available. 
You can put a check while listing row data in php.

Comment: Come on. Stop with the deprecated API already!

Answer (score 1):

use mysql `Count`

```
SELECT count(username) FROM users WHERE username ='xyz'
```

And your `$last_limt` is not grater than `total count-1`

Comment: Can you be more specific please .

        $count = SELECT count(username) FROM users WHERE username ='xyz'
if($last_limt<=$count-1){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username[$x] . "' LIMIT " . $last_limt . " , " . $nxt_limt . "");
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to check number of rows of the result from that query before proceeding

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username[$x] . "' LIMIT " . $last_limt . " , " . $nxt_limt . "");
$rowcount=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount > 0)
{
    //next operations

}
else
{
    //No more data
}
```

Comment: ya it was , But the problem was i used  return null in else case . while any of query return null the entire result was returned as null . Now i solved that

Comment: In that case you can return empty array in else